# AngularJS code not working in WordPress plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress

I have written some code using AngularJS to return my reviews from database. It properly works in the local server and in the real server as well.

But the problem comes when I insert this code in a custom plugin in WordPress. I use the plugin *icegram* for popup the review. I think my AngularJS library file is not found properly by WordPress, so it happens.

I put the link to the library file in the header and footer, but it still does not work. How can I solve this issue?

```
var app = angular.module('reviewRecordList', []);
app.controller('dispalyReview', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://website.com/reviewaide/reviewOAK/ajsCheckList.php")
      .then(function (response) {
        $scope.checkList = response.data.reviewRecords;
        $scope.review_at = $scope.checkList[0].review_at;
    });
});
```

This code works locally and on another server without WordPress.